Does Any Inline Button Always Behave as Inline-Block?
I'm trying to understand this behavior where an inline button behaves like an inline-block, in that its background extends to fill the entire line height:


html {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 35em;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.background {
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  all: unset;
}

button:focus {
  outline: revert;
}

div {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
<html>

<div>
  <span class="background">I am a span</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="background">I am a button</button>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="background inline-block">I am an inline block</span>
</div>

</html>



The button's background extends the full line height, even though the computed style, according to my browser is inline.
To make sure I understand - is the HTML spec basically saying that an inline button is always an inline block? Or is something else going on.

If the button's computed value of the display property is inline then yes, the spec says that it will behave as inline-block. There is currently no way to make it behave like a non-atomic inline box (i.e. like a reguilar span).
